# Want to create pokemon fan-game, need advice on copyright

Tags: legal

I want to create a pokemon text game. Obviously I will use various stuff that belongs to Nintendo, like pokemon, professor, region names and sprites from the games. Can Nintendo sue me or take down my game and for what? What are the possibilities?

I think it's important to note that:

- It is a text adventure game that lacks any mechanics of known official games
- It is going to be absolutely non-profit, I won't accept any money, including donations, for my creation
- It is going to be based on a website
- I'm not expecting more than 1000 users per day to visit it
- To sum up, the IP of Nintendo I want to use are pokemon sprites and various names, copyrighted by Nintendo
- There are a lot of pokemon web-games operating like neopets that weren't currently shut down

I would be very thankful for any advice or help!

p.s. Sorry for my bad English, that's not my mother tongue. :^)

Comment: "I'm not making profit" / "It's not going to be popular" / "Other people are doing it" are not legal defenses. You are taking content that is not yours and using it without the permission of the creators, and they are in their legal rights to send you a cease and desist notice or have your game taken down.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the answer! :^)

Comment: We also have [other questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blegal%5D+pokemon) that discuss this topic.

Comment: Thank you as well!

Comment: Neopets is not a pokemon game.It has no connection to Pokemon except that it has monsters which can be trained. Game mechanic concepts are usually the part of a game which is the least protected by intellectual property law.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I understand! I was talking about games like pokefarm q and pokeheroes, which operate like pet clicking games. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Lagoat Yes, those look like obvious copyright and trademark infringement which can be shut down easily when the Nintendo legal department has nothing better to do. I am sure they have a long todo-list, so they might not have gotten to those yet.